# How to prevent a component from redrawing vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm using vue-router in my project.
I pass components through router-view.
But I want to change the url without rendering the components.
I tried router.push and router.replace but they all redraw the components.
I have this kind of watch in which I want to check, if there is a query parameter, then do one logic, and if it is not there, then go to another

```
watch(
() => currentRouter.fullPath,
() => {
  if (!JSON.parse(currentRouter?.query?.render)) {
    refresh()
  } else {}
}
```

)

Comment: You can try `v-once` or `v-memo` https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-once

Comment: Could be XY problem. Consider explaining your case in details